# ion-content overlap with ion-header-bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building phonegap apps based on ionic framework. In one html page, I need one header and one content.But the header overlaps with the content. I am sorry I have no enough reputation to post the image.

The code is following. The html page is in the same folder with lib folder, which contains the ionic css and js folders.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather</title>

    <!-- Sets initial viewport load and disables zooming  -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/css/ionic.css">

    <script src="lib/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/js/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
          <h1 class="title">Settings</h1>
          <button class="button button-clear" ng-click="closeSettings()">Close</button>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content has-header="true">
          <div class="padding">
            <div class="list">
              <label class="item item-input">
                <span class="input-label">Units</span>

                <ion-radio-buttons ng-model="settings.tempUnits">
                  <button class="button button-positive button-radio" ng-value="'f'">&deg;F</button>
                  <button class="button button-positive button-radio" ng-value="'c'">&deg;C</button>
                </ion-radio-buttons>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ion-content>

    <!-- <ion-pane id="wrapper"> -->
<!--        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-dark">
            <button class="button icon-left ion-chevron-left button-clear button-dark" onclick="goBack()">Back</button>
            <div class="title">xxx</div>
            <button class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
        </ion-header-bar>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 89, accepted):

see:http://jsbin.com/pagacohovohe/1/edit

Give class="has-header" to ion-content.

```
<ion-content class="has-header">
</ion-content>
```

And you need to initialise your angular app - See javascript on my example. Note ng-controller and ng-app.

Comment: Thanks. But they still overlaps.

Comment: @ChengchengPei try my new answer.

Comment: Thanks. But They still overlaps.

Comment: @ChengchengPei check the link I posted.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I used the javascript you gave me to initialize the html page and now it works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This happens if your javascript code has some error. It prevents ioinc from  setting up the view-title and in turn adding the "has-header" automatically.

Comment: This is happening to me and I don't understand where is the error. Ionic Serve console doesn't show any errors and I check my code is like the link in this answer.

Comment: Same here. App initialised. has-header added. But just doesn't fix. Only able to fix with additional DIV and "padding" class. That add additional spacing between content and header. Not cool. Still hoping to find the real cause and real fix. But because of rushing for completion, I'll just take the extra DIV wrapper with padding class as temporary fix.

Comment: Thanks that works however if I want common content declaration in main index.html template that includes other partials seems  <ion-nav-view ></ion-nav-view> breaks if embedded like that

Answer (score 14):

Came here having same problem with Ionic 2: Navbar overlaps content. In my case, it was because I had an *ngIf on ion-content. Solution was to move *ngIf into inner element, eg ng-container (Thanks @TwitchBronBron):

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      ...
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <ng-container *ngIf="...">...</ng-container>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was my problem!  Any idea if this would cause issues with the footer nav bar doing the same thing?

Comment: If you don't want to add a new element, you could also use `<ng-container *ngIf="...">...</ng-container>`

Answer (score 6):

You may try to set 'has-subheader' class like this

```
    <ion-content class='has-header has-subheader'>
    ...
    </ion-content>
```

See: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#subheader

Answer (score 6):

```
<ion-view view-title="BBS">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">
        <div class="button-bar">
            <a class="button">web game</a>
            <a class="button">mobile game</a>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content class="has-header">

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the first  on  has an *ngIf with data based on user roles which i get after a user is logged in. I end up with this item not shown after login. After first login when the data is stored in storage then the item shows.

Answer (score 0):

has-header and any css class & property not working in ionic. 
**You can try padding-top**

```
<ion-content padding-top>
<ion-grid padding-top>
  <ion-row padding-top>
    <ion-col padding-top>

        <ion-card class="foodCard">
          <img src="#">

            <ion-card-header>
              <ion-card-title>Card Title</ion-card-title>
            </ion-card-header>

            <ion-card-content>
              Keep close to Nature's heart... and break clear away, once in awhile,
              and climb a mountain.
            </ion-card-content>

          </ion-card> 

    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```